# pjax still does full page reload

Tags: javascript, jquery, pjax

I have tried pjax examples in chrome and firefox, i took the sample code and placed it into my own app but it still does a full page reload. The AJAX request happens then the page moves on without updating the #main div

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.0/jquery-1.8.0.min.js"></script>
        <script src="http://localhost:8888/jul/js/jquery.pjax.js"></script>


         <script type="text/javascript">
            // $(document).ready(function(){
            //   $('a[data-pjax]').pjax();
            // })

        // $(document).ready(function(){
        //     $('a').pjax({

        //    container: '#main'
        //  })
        $('document').ready(function(){
           $('ul a').pjax('#main')
        });


         </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        11:59:36        <div id="main">
             <div class='loader' style='display:none'><img src='http://localhost:8888/jul/imgs/spinner.gif'></div><ul>

  <li><a data-pjax='#main' href="/jul/stats/pjax_stats/index/">Index</a></li>
  <li><a data-pjax='#main' href="/jul/stats/pjax_stats/total_posts/">total_posts</a></li>

  <li><a data-pjax='#main' href="http://localhost:8888/jul/stats/pjax_stats/index">Index</a></li>
  <li><a data-pjax='#main' href="http://localhost:8888/jul/stats/pjax_stats/total_posts">total_posts</a></li>
  <li><a href="http://localhost:8888/jul/stats/pjax_stats/total_graph">total_graph</a></li>
  <li><a href="http://localhost:8888/jul/stats/pjax_stats/twitter_graph">twitter_graph</a></li>
  <li><a href="http://localhost:8888/jul/stats/pjax_stats/facebook_graph">facebook_graph</a></li>
</ul>index files




        </div>

    </body>
</html>
```

I have tried multiple methods to invoke pjax and maybe someone else could point out where i am going wrong? The Ajax/GET seems to return fine in firebug console- this is an example of my php that produces the pjax response

```
public function total_posts(){
        // print_r($_SERVER);

        if (!isset($_SERVER["X_PJAX"])) {
            $this->load->view('stats/pjax_stats/header');
            $this->load->view('stats/pjax_stats/links');
        }else{
            echo "pjax";//add in for debug
        }

        echo "total posts";

        if (!isset($_SERVER['X-PJAX'])) {
            $this->load->view('stats/pjax_stats/footer');
        }



    }
```

**A bug?**

There seems to be a bug in the latest version where the append variable to the end of the url where the ajax request  is made to is _pjax=container instead of _pjax=true

Comment: What is the `responseText` of the AJAX request?

Comment: if i persist firebug... the response is simple "total posts" which is expected then it does a full refresh.

Comment: There was a [bug report](https://github.com/defunkt/jquery-pjax/issues/170) for jquery-pjax with jquery-1.8. Maybe it's worth trying again with the very latest HEAD.

Comment: i built a version from github (v1.8.1pre) and still not working

Comment: Sorry, I was suggesting the latest version of jquery-pjax, not the latest version of jquery.

Comment: For me, pjax works perfectly on live server, while on my laptop it doesn't, on my friend's laptop works good because his lap is better

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Have you tried setting the timeout higher (default < 1s )?

For example:

```
$('document').ready(function(){
  $('ul a').pjax({
    container: '#main',
    timeout: 5000 #ms
  });
});
```

Comment: What does timeout in PJAX do? It waits for server response for `timeout` time, and if server didnt respond it makes full page reload?

Comment: It seems that `$(document).on("pjax:timeout", function() { return false; });` solves the problem too (it's equivalent to setting the timeout to infinity).

Comment: I see default timeout set to 0 in jQuery Pjax lib.

Comment: Wow.  After all my debugging this is exactly what it turned out to be. It must be really low by default.

Comment: @AshitVora default timeout value is 650ms. Read [here](https://github.com/defunkt/jquery-pjax)

Answer (score 0):

I thought I would add an answer since I got this problem today and this was the first Google result.

Before you go changing the timeout make sure your container exists. This may sound obvious but if your using a framework, say Yii2 (PHP), you will find that your container ID may no longer exist between refreshes, hence pjax is refreshing the whole page.

So as a note: make sure your container exists before you tweak with timeouts.

Comment: What do you exactly mean by **container**?

Comment: @choxx so the PJAX when you go to construct it in many cases attaches to an element with which to load content into, that is the container

Comment: got it. But I think my issue is not related with container. After around 15 minutes of first page load, my page goes refresh in Yii2. Probably it is due to server's late response.

Comment: @choxx have you checked dev tools in your browser to see what network parts are saying?

Comment: I tried waiting for it's happening in Networks section in chrome but when I thought of looking at it continuously for the main reason, then browser tricks me. Then it is not going to refresh page!! My bad luck because of some mishappening :(

Comment: @choxx that is a tough one indeed hmm

Comment: I caught tricking of my browser,.. :p Yeah it was due to timeout property of PJAX. The default value is 650 ms. When response tooks more then this, it forces full page reload. I extend this to 5000 as per my requirement and it works like a charm.

Comment: @choxx thanks for getting back, I tried timeout on my stuff originally and I should probably have thought about that :) Glad to hear

Comment: Also i think the problem of non existence of container arises when your js loaded before the container's creation. Being on safe side I always call my js/jquery stuff on `$(document).ready(function(){});` and suggest the same to everybody.

Comment: @choxx well, this problem is within the way that pjax handles a non-existent container. Even if you bind the JS to document it will still reload the page since you need an element to assign a pjax view to